# Original draft-js and forked draft-js, have a different structure when installed

Tags: github, draftjs, git-fork

Why original draft-js and my forked draft-js, have a different structure when installed?

The screenshot below is the structure of my forked draft-js
[image]

The screenshot below is the structure of original draft-js
[image]

Draft-js version : "0.10.5"

MacOS High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

Check your branch/version: [in 0.10.x](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/tree/0.10.0-alpha), you will see a similar structure.

The original repo [`facebook/draft-js`](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js) is on master, the most recent version, with additional files.